# java.util.zip.ZipException when calling a Java adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have an ZipException (zip file is empty) when calling an adapter. IBM MobileFirst Platform seems to have problems to load classes that is deployed and compiled in the adapter file (I checked the compiled .adapter file, all classes are there and OK). I've tryed to delete/recreated the server, re-re-redeploy, ... 
There's no error when deploying and in the operations console everything is OK (adapter, methods,urls).

the exception:

```
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:821 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:821 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.adapters.rest.ParentLastClassLoader.findResourceInURL(ParentLastClassLoader.java:522)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:822 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.adapters.rest.ParentLastClassLoader.internalFindResource(ParentLastClassLoader.java:472)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.adapters.rest.ParentLastClassLoader.internalFindClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:212)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.adapters.rest.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:128)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:115)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:181)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:823 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:150)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:268)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:129)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.getDatatypeFactory(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:741)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$13.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:575)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$13.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:551)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:824 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.FilterTransducer.parse(FilterTransducer.java:69)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:230)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:50)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:549)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:78)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:323)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:825 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:201)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:826 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:170)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:826 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:355)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:826 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:109)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:826 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:222)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:826 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:539)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:827 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:827 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:827 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:827 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy213.rechercherContrats(Unknown Source)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:827 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at fr.sma.prod.adapter.ContratResource.rechercherContrats(Unknown Source)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:828 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler$1.run(WorklightWinkHandler.java:50)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler$1.run(WorklightWinkHandler.java:45)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:829 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.accessTheResourceWithIdentity(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:96)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.access$000(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:39)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:84)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:81)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter$1.run(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:154)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter$1.run(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:145)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:830 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:831 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:831 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.oauth.validation.ValidationFilterHelper.filterRequest(ValidationFilterHelper.java:65)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:831 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter.securedAccessToResource(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:145)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:831 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter.filterRequest(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:112)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:831 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.handleRequest(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:81)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler.handleRequest(WorklightWinkHandler.java:45)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:832 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:833 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:834 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:835 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:836 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:837 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:838 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:838 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox$2.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:347)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:839 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:84)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:352)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.doService(RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.java:69)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServlet.service(RESTAdaptersServlet.java:59)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:840 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:841 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:842 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:842 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:842 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:842 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:843 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:843 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:843 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:843 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 [9/30/15 15:09:37:843 CEST] 000000d0 SystemErr      R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm completly stuck with this. Has anyone an idea what could that be? (it's odd because it worked before).

my configuration:

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5 (wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202)
wlp.install.dir = C:/Users/axxxx/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20150807-0630/server/wlp/
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
java.version = 1.7.0_79
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.7.0_79-b15)
os = Windows 7 (6.1; amd64) (en_US)
```

Comment: As always, it is best if you can *provide a full reproduction of the problem you are facing so that it could be* **recreated** and debugged. Full code or a project with an adapter. Since you have it - provide it.

Comment: @Idan where can I send you the code? It is not a public or open source project, we are IBM customers and we don't want to publish all our sources.

Comment: We do not need the entire source, just a small test case that demonstrates it. Can you produce it? Maybe just replace your content with dummy content and provide the adapter?

Comment: Hi. I've seen a problem like it before. Can you please try something completely voodoo? Try to switch Eclipse to a new workspace and import the project (or create a new project, and put the Adapter in it). Then try to rebuild and deploy.

Comment: @MilanSMA, have you tried Issahar's suggestion? Are you able to provide a demo of the problem? Perhaps you would prefer to remove the question and open a PMR instead so you could supply the project there?

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Studio in Eclipse sometimes acts strangely with class loading in adapters. One suggestion you may try is the following:

1. Backup your Studio
2. Create a new Eclipse workspace
3. Import a backup of your project
4. Re-build and deploy the project

Verify that the issue has been resolved.